# Read Data when activity is started

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to implement something like within my recycler view I wanted to show CONSTANT UP TO DATE data, which is the "ROOMSTATUS"

Imagine, I have two different accounts one is Staff Account and Customer Account, when a customer added his desired item to the shopping cart, the room status is available so apparently, the customer is able to do so

However, if the customer hasn't check-out of that specific item, and there is a sudden change in the staff side for example the staff changes that specific item that the customer has added into his shopping cart which becomes unavailable, this means it will not let the customer check out that specific item, but what I want to do is just to have the text displayed on the recycler view which is similar to the text on the item choosing list.

But, whenever i went into that activity it crashed, and gave me this error,

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
> ```
>
> reference
> at com.example.fyptest1.CustomerBookedRoomAdapter$1.onDataChange(CustomerBookedRoomAdapter.java:54)"

I think it says, updatedRoomStatus = snapshot.child("roomstatus").getValue().toString();
this line is not getting any data from the firebase right, but i can assure there is data within

I'm not sure if it was because onDataChanged keyword that I've implemented, is that any other way to fix this?

```
@Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull CustomerBookedRoomAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull RoomDataForAdapter model) {

        roomnameunderCustomerBooked = model.getRoomname();
        dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms");

        dataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.child(roomnameunderCustomerBooked).child("roomname").exists()){
                    String updatedRoomStatus = "";
                    updatedRoomStatus = snapshot.child("roomstatus").getValue().toString();


                    holder.roomName.setText(model.getRoomname());
                    holder.roomType.setText(model.getRoomtype());
                    holder.roomCapacity.setText(model.getRoomcapacity());

                    if(updatedRoomStatus.equals("Available")){
                        String  availaFormat = "Available      ";
                        holder.roomStatus.setText(availaFormat);
                        holder.roomStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#226600"));
                    }else if(updatedRoomStatus.equals("Unavailable")){
                        String  unavailaFormat = "Unavailable   ";
                        holder.roomStatus.setText(unavailaFormat);
                        holder.roomStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C91818"));
                    }else if(updatedRoomStatus.equals("Maintenance")){
                        String  umFormat = "Under\nMaintenance";
                        holder.roomStatus.setText(umFormat);
                        holder.roomStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCAA00"));

                        //Set room "Under Maintenance" word alignment in a proper way
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(29,-28,0,0);
                        holder.roomStatus.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                    else{

                        
                    }
                    holder.roomPrice.setText(model.getRoomprice());
                    holder.roomCharacteristics.setText(model.getRoomcharacteristics());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImageurl()).fit().into(holder.roomImage);

                }else{
                    
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

this is my database structure

```
{
  "Customer" : {
    "tjing123" : {
      "email" : "jh@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "JingHuan",
      "password" : "1",
      "username" : "tjing123"
    }
  },
  "CustomerBookedRooms" : {
    "tjing123" : {
      "Always" : {
        "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2F20476d50-0256-4637-a85f-88cfb0d49509%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A76555?alt=media&token=9042d0c2-1203-48a9-85e0-66de5c30eb84",
        "roombedcounts" : "One Bed",
        "roomcapacity" : "1 pax",
        "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
        "roomname" : "Always",
        "roomprice" : "588.00",
        "roomstatus" : "Available",
        "roomtype" : "Single Room",
        "username" : "tjing123"
      },
      "Kokomi" : {
        "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2F175ac041-af4d-4ffd-8b0f-0f04f3b293f5%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider%2F0%2F1%2Fmediakey%253A%252Flocal%25253Ab456c215-0536-4e05-8f77-616f83d36055%2FORIGINAL%2FNONE%2F1931479739?alt=media&token=1cab4f94-929f-4f52-8a46-aa76c82a0848",
        "roombedcounts" : "Two Beds",
        "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
        "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
        "roomname" : "Kokomi",
        "roomprice" : "499.00",
        "roomstatus" : "Available",
        "roomtype" : "Couple Room",
        "username" : "tjing123"
      },
      "The Nuts" : {
        "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2Fd0f0279a-121b-4747-bdf0-76c9e7bfb30c%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A76556?alt=media&token=e234d404-adfd-4a64-b180-50408c90a823",
        "roombedcounts" : "One Bed",
        "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
        "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
        "roomname" : "The Nuts",
        "roomprice" : "258.00",
        "roomstatus" : "Available",
        "roomtype" : "Master Room",
        "username" : "tjing123"
      }
    }
  },
  "Rooms" : {
    "Always" : {
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2F20476d50-0256-4637-a85f-88cfb0d49509%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A76555?alt=media&token=9042d0c2-1203-48a9-85e0-66de5c30eb84",
      "roombedcounts" : "One Bed",
      "roomcapacity" : "1 pax",
      "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
      "roomid" : "1111",
      "roomname" : "Always",
      "roomprice" : "588.00",
      "roomstatus" : "Maintenance",
      "roomtype" : "Single Room"
    },
    "HEHE" : {
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2F36b436d2-0897-41a3-9d08-0ec48ec13a5d%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A25?alt=media&token=2984d69a-b52c-4003-9adc-eb7556b97bf7",
      "roombedcounts" : "Three Beds",
      "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
      "roomcharacteristics" : "Scenery View",
      "roomid" : "1111",
      "roomname" : "HEHE",
      "roomprice" : "399.00",
      "roomstatus" : "Maintenance",
      "roomtype" : "Master Room"
    },
    "Huan&Jian" : {
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2Fd8ad8454-29b4-4a44-b2c0-4da584c0cf17%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A71334?alt=media&token=0cbd8564-adbd-4a69-8bbb-4c0b8af1ab5c",
      "roombedcounts" : "One Bed",
      "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
      "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
      "roomid" : "1314",
      "roomname" : "Huan&Jian",
      "roomprice" : "188.00",
      "roomstatus" : "Maintenance",
      "roomtype" : "Couple Room"
    },
    "Kokomi" : {
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2F175ac041-af4d-4ffd-8b0f-0f04f3b293f5%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider%2F0%2F1%2Fmediakey%253A%252Flocal%25253Ab456c215-0536-4e05-8f77-616f83d36055%2FORIGINAL%2FNONE%2F1931479739?alt=media&token=1cab4f94-929f-4f52-8a46-aa76c82a0848",
      "roombedcounts" : "Two Beds",
      "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
      "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
      "roomid" : "5555",
      "roomname" : "Kokomi",
      "roomprice" : "499.00",
      "roomstatus" : "Available",
      "roomtype" : "Couple Room"
    },
    "The Nuts" : {
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/finalyearprojectapplicat-8a301.appspot.com/o/RoomImageStorage%2Fd0f0279a-121b-4747-bdf0-76c9e7bfb30c%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A76556?alt=media&token=e234d404-adfd-4a64-b180-50408c90a823",
      "roombedcounts" : "One Bed",
      "roomcapacity" : "2 pax",
      "roomcharacteristics" : "Cozy",
      "roomid" : "7272",
      "roomname" : "The Nuts",
      "roomprice" : "258.00",
      "roomstatus" : "Available",
      "roomtype" : "Master Room"
    }
  },
  "Staff" : {
    "tt" : {
      "email" : "rayray@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "raymondting",
      "password" : "Abcbc123456789!",
      "username" : "tt"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have attached my database structure, please take a look @AlexMamo, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `roomnameunderCustomerBooked` holds the value of `Always`, for example, when you are using the following statement:

```
if(snapshot.child(roomnameunderCustomerBooked).child("roomname").exists()){...}
```

It basically means that you are trying to check the value under the below reference exists:

```
root/Rooms/Always/roomname
```

And it does, the value being `Always`. However, when you are trying to read the value of `roomstatus` using this line:

```
updatedRoomStatus = snapshot.child("roomstatus").getValue().toString();
```

It makes sense to get a NullPOinterEception, since right under the `Rooms` node there is no `roomstatus` child. This child exists right under `Always`, which is missing from your referece. So please change the above line of code to:

```
updatedRoomStatus = snapshot
    .child(roomnameunderCustomerBooked)
    .child("roomstatus")
    .getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: Ive changed it, but it still getting the data within the table CustomerBookedRooms and not getting the data within the Rooms table

Comment: For example, in table Rooms, there a room named called Always, and the status is Maintenance, i wanted to show this Maintenance word within the CustomerBookedRooms table, however i know that the room status within the CustomerBookedRooms is not similar , that is why, before all those data being assigned into respective textview, i checked room status and my intention is i always want to make sure the roomstatus data is getting from there instead of getting it from CustomerBookedRooms table.

Comment: It cannot since the `dataRef` reference points to `Rooms` node. And yes, this should displayed `"roomstatus" : "Maintenance",`.

Comment: But why is my data is still getting from CustomerBookedRooms table instead of getting it from the Rooms table?

Comment: It's because you attach `addValueEventListener` on the `dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms");` object that points exactly to the `Rooms` node, right?

Comment: Yeah and that is wanted but it seems the data they retrieve is from the CustomerBookedRooms instead of Rooms

Comment: It cannot get data from another node, as long as the reference points to the `Rooms` node. Try to use a hard-coded value. Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: hold on a second

Comment: Yep still the same

Comment: As what i see from here, i think it couldnt compare the value with the specified reference i dont know why @Alex Mamo

Comment: In that case, the value is probably coming from another part of your code. There is definitely no way you can read data from a specific node without directly pointing to that node.